# How to make get request using query with boolean type?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am doing an Alamofire request, and now I need to do a get request. In this request I should send query that is in Bool type(picture is in below link). This is my method to do request.

```
 func setupRequest(path: Paths, method: RequestMethod, body: Encodable? = nil, params: [String: Any]? = nil, header: HeaderType, completion: @escaping((Result<Data,NetworkError>) -> Void)) {}
```

I am sending this arguments. How can I send the demanded query?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgVZ6.png

Comment: In params: `[isMain: true]` might do the trick.

Comment: Tip: when learning how to do HTTP and implementing and testing network requests, it would be _far easier_ to compose your URLRequest directly and use URLSession to execute it. Also, you may try a Server's  API with tools like cURL on the command line, or use tools like Postman. Also, questions that may come up, will be _far more easy_ to answer, than when starting "I use Alamofire ..."   ;)

Comment: this didn't work(  @Larme

Comment: And how did you construct the request? You need to put that value into the query, Alamofire give that possibility. Now, depending on how you construct the request, it might be correct or not. Including: do the API expects "true" or "1" (there is an option for that). But without your attempt/code, it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was the correct one, I put that in my params and it worked for me. In the first try it wasn't working, but now it works. @Larme